# File Name too big in QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I am using a QTableWidget with multiple columns.. One column is for the filename which is very long so I have to stretch the column every time.Is there any method by which i can sort out this problem???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inherited [functions](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#resizeColumnsToContents):

```
void QTableView::resizeColumnsToContents();
```

or

```
void QTableView::resizeColumnToContents (int column);
```

every time you changed the filename. That should be faster and easier than stretching it according to the filename's length.

---

You can also try using [setResizeMode](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode):

```
tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

I've never used it, but it looks promising. This should make the columns resize automatically,

Comment: I dont have any QTableView object in my code..do I need to initialize one??

Comment: QTableWidget inherits from QTableView, so all QTableView's functions are available for you.

Comment: Oh Sorry It worked bt it looks a bit awful..Is it possible to implement vertical scroll bar for single column of a QTableWidget??